# Nginx rewrite wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, nginx, url-rewriting

I have WordPress (example.com) on nginx with created page A, which has permalink **example.com/a** .
Wordpress doesn't have page with permalink **example.com/b** .

I want to inner rewrite uri **/b** to show page **/a**, that is when user types **example.com/b** , WP should return the page as it was request as **example.com/a** (no 301/302 redirection).

I tried with various nginx configurations:

```
# this returns 404
location /b  {
    rewrite ^ /a last;
}

# this returns 302 redirect to example.com/a
location /b  {
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/dev/shm/.php-fpm/socket;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 45;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 15;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO "/a";
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI "/a";
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root/index.php;
}

# same as above
location /b {
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO "/a";
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI "/a";
}
```

How can this be achieved?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first rewrite should work, how do you handle the php ?
could you write the php handling block please ?

Comment: Its regular WordPress installation. No rewrite/redirect plugins. It has a lot of code, see "The WordPress Include Flow" on [page here](http://wpmu.org/wordpress-query-overview-how-a-page-request-is-translated-to-a-mysql-query/)

Answer (score 0):

No need to put it in a location {} block, you can just use

```
rewrite ^b$ /a last;
```

And don't forgot to reload nginx after adding the rule.